# MUI DatePicker component show StaticTimePicker instead of normal TimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We have a requirement to choose a date along with the time in our UI. We are using material UI DateTimePicker for implementing this. DatePicker is working fine without any problem, but we need a customization, instead of showing the default TimePicker shown after selecting the date we should show the StaticTimePicker from the material UI. If you know to override the default, please let me know.

stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1g6tf3

material UI documentation links:
https://v5.mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/
https://v5.mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/static-time-picker/#demos

Thanks in advance